# How to plot histogram with numerical and string data with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a csv file. It contains two column called Devices (String values) and AverageTime ( float, numeric value).  I need to plot histogram, x axis: Devices, y axis: AverageTime. My code is

```
T=readtable('H:/Temporary/test.csv');
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'Devices' 'Time'};
Devices1=T.Devices;
Time1=T.Time;
hist(Devices1, Time1);
```

But I'm getting error

> Error using hist (line 48)
>     Input arguments must be numeric.
>   Error in test (line 5)
>     hist(Devices1, Time1)

Please help me to plot this?

> ```
> My csv file looks like: (just an example)
> Devices      AverageTime
> A            10.23
> B            22.38
> C            78.20
> D            100.002
> E            57.1147
> ```

Comment: Try [`str2num`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to convert your string values to numeric ones.

Comment: Do you mean to say that devices are repeated in the CSV file, and you want to add values for the same device?

Comment: Cris, I modified my question and just added my csv file. I need to plot this as a histogram. X axis is each devices and Y axis their Values.

Comment: Are you sure you want a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) and not a [bar graph](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using bar rather than hist, you only have to set the XtickLabel to show device name like this

```
bar(Time1)
set(gca,'xticklabel',Devices1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! . Please can you tell me how to make label of X axis ( devices name) more clear and visible. In my case they are overlapping.

Comment: In my case I have 188 devices. I need to plot them all more clearly with their device  names.

Comment: well, you can add to set command more attributes like 'FontSize', 12  or 
 'FontName','TimesNewRoman' . you can also rotate the names with xtickangle